# Login script executed as root during Login cannot get current logged in user

Tags: bash

I am struggling with how to get the user who logged into a macbook within a login script that is executed as the root user. The scenario is that I have a bunch of macbooks in my school that have a login script that is run every time a user logs into the computer. I rely on this script to determine what DNS servers they should use, etc.

This script used to get the user just by grabbing $3, but now that is no longer working, and running various commands to determine who is logged in just shows root each time, even tho I am logging in as various students. The script:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Setting DNS by User

# Get variables. $3 is logging in user.
user=$3

thisuser1=`logname`
thisuser2=`id -u -n`
thisuser3=`id -u`

echo -e "Current User: $user\n"
echo -e "logname  = $thisuser1"
echo -e "id -u -n = $thisuser2"
echo -e "id -u.   = $thisuser3"
```

Yields:

```
Current User:

logname = root
id -u -n = root
id -u. = 0
```

I am at a loss. During this run I logged in as a user named 'eric'. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: There can be multiple users logged into a Mac. `logname` returns the user logged into the terminal where the script is being run.

Comment: Because of Fast User Switching.

Comment: Does this mean that if I turn off fast user switching the script would work normally again?

Comment: No. Fast User Switching just explains why the concept of "the logged-in user" doesn't exist and tools like `logname` refer to the current terminal, not the system as a whole.